# Reset commit in SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have 2 branches `master` and `bugfix`. my current branch is `bugfix`, where I have committed my changes (not pushed), now I need to reset this commit.

If I do reset my commit, will it affect other commits in `master` branch?

**Actually I want to remove this commit.**

```
git reset --soft 734e3a0
```

I am using SourceTree.

Comment: `git reset --soft` does not "affect" commits, rather it moves the `HEAD` of your branch to point to a different commit.  Can you update your question with what is your situation for wanting to do this?

Comment: Take a look at the edited answer below.

Comment: Check this out: https://www.attosol.com/undo-in-git-using-sourcetree/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to run this command in source tree terminal  `git reset --soft HEAD~1` this command push back your commit in your sourtree. then you take latest pull and then you can commit your code.

Answer (score 10):

Simply

- go to Log/History in source tree,
- select the previous commit of the commit which you want to undo and
- right click and do '*Reset current branch to this commit*'

This will discard your committed changes (which were not pushed).
It won't impact anything in master branch.

Answer (score 4):

If you have not pushed your code to remote you can revert your change by following below steps shown as in the image.**But please BACKUP your Changes first** [image: revert changes]
1. Go to SourseTree terminal 
2. Execute the command  `git reset HEAD~` 
Then go to file status and check.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think doing a `git reset --soft` will affect any commits.  It will only affect your branch.

If you want to revert commit `734e3a0` then you can try using `git revert`:

```
git revert 734e3a0
```

This will instruct Git to add a new commit which undoes whatever `734e3a0` was doing originally.  Note that this is a good option in the event that this commit is in the middle of a branch, and it is also a good option for a branch whose history has already been made public.

Comment: I agree, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: the question was pretty clear. A reset is wanted and possible since the commit was not pushed. A revert would result in an additional commit.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to ask yourself what you want to do.

What is `reset` is for?

I assume you want to ***`undo`*** your changes. Do do so you have several options, which you can read about in details in here:

**[How to move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716)**

It will explain in details what to do in each option.

---

#### ***`What needs to be done?`***

You have to set up your HEAD to point to a new (or old) commit.
The above post will show you and will teach you what to do and will show you few options.